# Reading and Writing with Typescript in Firebase with Node.js

Tags: node.js, typescript, firebase, express, firebase-realtime-database

I am attempting to use Typescript in a Node.js/Express project because I prefer strict typing. However, I am new to Typescript.

My goal is to save data using firebase and typescript (not google cloud functions).

My architecture is as follows:

1. API POST for `/people/create` comes in with JSON {name: "Guy"}
2. We create a `Person` object in the router then send it to the `DatabaseManager` (`write_person(person)`)
3. `DatabaseManager` creates an Firebase friendly object out of the Person object and sends it to `FirebaseManager.write(FirebaseReferences.People, data)`
4. `FirebaseManager` saves this data to firebase and returns to `DatabaseManager` which returns to router call.

---

```
router.post('/person/create', (req: Request, res: Response) => {
    var person: Person = new Person(req.json...name);
    var uuid: String = DatabaseManager.write_person(person);
    res.send(uuid);
});
```

---

```
export module DatabaseManager {
    export function write_person(person: Person): String {
        return FirebaseManager.write(FirebaseReferences.People, person.to_dict());
    }
}
```

---

```
export enum FirebaseReferences {
    People = "/people"
}

export module FirebaseManager {

    export function write(ref: FirebaseReferences, data: object): String {
        try {
            var new_ref: firebase.database.Reference = db.ref(ref.toString());
            var uuid: String = new_ref.push(data).key;
            return uuid;
        } catch (error) {
            console.log("FirebaseManager, write(): " + error);
            throw error;
        }
    }
}
```

---

I get this following error:

```
app/database_manager/FirebaseManager.ts:33:17 - error TS2322: Type 'string | null' is not assignable to type 'String'.
  Type 'null' is not assignable to type 'String'.

33             var uuid: String = new_ref.push(data).key;
                   ~~~~

[6:29:05 PM] Found 1 error. Watching for file changes.
```

Answer (score 2):

[`DatabaseReference.key`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.Reference#key) returns a nullable type as indicated by `string | null` in the error message. You assign to a `String`, which is non-nullable, so the compiler correctly concludes that the types are incompatible.

You either need to assign to a nullable type, or convert the nullable string to a non-nullable one.

#### assign to a nullable type

```
var uuid?: string = new_ref.push(data).key;
```

#### convert the key to a non-nullable string

```
let key = new_ref.push(data).key;
var uuid: string = key !== null ? key : "";
```

Comment: Do I have to worry about the uuid always being null or is the call synchronous?

Comment: The keys are generated client-side. They're statistically guaranteed to be unique.